# Update database android application from a web site

Tags: android, database

I want to create an application which has a button on my menu that the user can click and it will replace and download the database which is provided on my website. The button already exist and the problem is how to replace and download it from a web site?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever user click on button 1) you need to remove all the data from database. 2)Starting inserting data which is present on website by parsing the xml which will holds information present in Website.

Comment: how to parsing xml? sorry I am newbie

Answer (score 0):

```
1) Make HTTP connection with website.
2) check for new data are available on net or not.
3) if new data are available on net then download all new data then you have two choice.
   1.update existing data.
   2.Truncate existing data and insert newly downloaded data.
```

Comment: how to insert newly downloaded data?

Comment: Please search through stackoverflow .. you will get the answer for sure. The question to interact with database has bee asked many times. Moreover as Dr Jackal has said just truncate the existing data insert newly downloaded data.